# Renaming PPT picture using VBA Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

After I have updated the series on a chart I have been trying to copy and paste an image of the chart into a PowerPoint using VBA. As soon as the image is pasted I want to rename the image. There will be many images of previous charts already on the PowerPoint. As soon as I paste the image I was thinking I could rename using code such as below while the picture is active.

```
With ActiveShape
.name="Batch1"
end with
```

I keep getting "Object Required" error messages. How can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: There's no `ActiveShape`, but I think (untested) that you can just refer to the latest shape by index, e.g. with `.Shapes.Count`.

Comment: Adding to @BigBen's suggetion, assuming a reference to the current slide in oSl, then oSl.Shapes(oSl.Shapes.Count) will do it.